# Develop a mobile application based on an existing Django website/app

Tags: android, python, ios, django

We have a website written in Django, that has been running for a few years. Now we would like to develop a mobile application for Android and iOS, using as much as possible from the Django-site.
E.g. classes from models, like users and relevant functions, other data, etc

What would be the best/easiest way to approach this issue.
We have been looking at several other questions like this, but all seem to be a few years old

Is there any options to using e.g. Django REST API?

We are just a group of students, and any help/pointers on where to start would be much appreciated!

Comment: Django REST API sound like a good idea.

Comment: Have you looked at Kivy? It isn't perfect but it might do: https://kivy.org/#home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mobile App you need to have APIs . So in Django, You can write APIs using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) or [tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) . You can use [Video](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAx4nmhI7S1RcPiaG-Uw0tg)
link to start writing the apis. If you want any detail help [click here](http://www.cdrf.co/)